# Can not create sharing rule on sandbox

Tags: sharing, sandbox, criteria-based-sharing

I have a sandbox and production environment set up. Sandbox is develop type.

There is a sharing rule on one of the objects (Survey__c) on Production. I took refresh of sandbox and now I am trying to create a new sharing rule in sandbox.

But it is having New button disabled. Also I can not Edit or Delete the existing sharing rule.

Any idea how I can add a new sharing rule in sandbox?

Thanks a lot,

Ray

Comment: Hi Ray - could this be profile related? There should not be any issues creating sharing rules in a sandbox.

Comment: Somehow this was related to refresh of sandbox and after the weekend I am able to access the New button on sharing rule now

Answer (score 3):

If you're using not standard Sys. Admin profile, validate that you user profile has **Administrative Permissions --> Manage Sharing** property is **checked**

[image]